# Creating workflows

Tags: sharepoint-designer

i am new to using share point design studio. I am trying to create a workflow that will send an email to the users manager when the user click save. Once the manager gets the email they have to enter the form and click approve and then another email goes to the requestor. I have built the form but i am having some issues with the workflow.

Any examples or advice is welcome.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Create a workflow in SPD and have it launched when an item is created or updated. When the check the approval status (there are conditions at the top). If the approval status is set to Approved, then choose the 'Send Email' option, in the To: category, choose function then 'Current Item: Created By'. If the approval status is set to Pending, then send the email to the manager (I assume you have a people picker to select the manager, or some other type of field to collect the managers email).

Comment: Thank you for responding, on the pending status part; i am wondering if the created by will automatically link back to that users managers? all the user information is in active directory

Comment: This might answer your question. the created by field I believe has the same back end as a people picker. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg602075.aspx